# MySQL Multiple unions with different parameters remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have one parent table and multiple child tables.

With a UNION statement I have been able to pull out the information from the children, but when I want to extract the items from the parent table that do not have a child table, the query just imports everything from the parent table again.

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT id, view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`
display_type AS display_type, NULL AS title, NULL AS `text`,
source_url AS source_url
FROM content_child_1
left JOIN content_parent
ON content_parent.id = content_child_1.view_ptr_id
UNION

SELECT id, view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`, 
NULL AS display_type, title AS title, NULL AS `text`,
NULL AS source_url
FROM content_child_2
LEFT JOIN content_parent
ON content_parent.id = content_child_2.view_ptr_id
UNION

SELECT DISTINCT id, NULL as view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`,
NULL AS display_type, NULL AS title, NULL AS `text`,
NULL AS source_url
FROM content_parent
```

For example:
- The first part of the query returns 10 items
- The second part of the query returns another 10 items
- The last part should also return 10 items (The ones without a child), but it returns 30 items.

I reality I have about 30 child tables with 20 fields, so if someone could tell me how to do this in a more simple way you are more then welcome.
The issue here is that all the child tables have columns of their own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LEFT OUTER JOINs in the last query, checking there is no matching record.

```
SELECT id, view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`
display_type AS display_type, NULL AS title, NULL AS `text`,
source_url AS source_url
FROM content_child_1
left JOIN content_parent
ON content_parent.id = content_child_1.view_ptr_id
UNION

SELECT id, view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`, 
NULL AS display_type, title AS title, NULL AS `text`,
NULL AS source_url
FROM content_child_2
LEFT JOIN content_parent
ON content_parent.id = content_child_2.view_ptr_id
UNION

SELECT DISTINCT id, NULL as view_ptr_id, parent_id, `name`,
NULL AS display_type, NULL AS title, NULL AS `text`,
NULL AS source_url
FROM content_parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN content_child_1
ON content_parent.id = content_child_1.view_ptr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN content_child_1
ON content_parent.id = content_child_2.view_ptr_id
WHERE content_child_1.view_ptr_id IS NULL
AND content_child_2.view_ptr_id IS NULL
```